# Retrieve documents from Completion Suggester using Elasticsearch Java API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

When I execute completion suggester request using curl, in the response I can find also the documents

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/shop/_search?pretty&size=20' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
    "suggest": {
        "product-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "phone",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "title",
                "skip_duplicates": true
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

the response

```
{
  "took" : 15,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "suggest" : {
    "product-suggest" : [
      {
        "text" : "phone",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 12,
        "options" : [
          {
            "text" : "Phone",
            "_index" : "shop",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "a02fd264-c25c-4634-8bd9-e275a293ce1d",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "title" : "Phone",
              "price" : 219.99
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, in the response I can find the document in the "_source" field.

Using Java API

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.suggest(new SuggestBuilder()
                .addSuggestion("product-suggest",
                        new CompletionSuggestionBuilder("title").prefix("phone").skipDuplicates(true)));
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

searchResponse.getSuggest().getSuggestion("product-suggest").getEntries().get(0).getOptions(.get(0).getText();
```

So, I can find the method to retrieve the text `getText`, but there are no method to retrieve the source.

Is there some way to retrieve the `source`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.Suggest suggest = searchResponse.getSuggest();
org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.completion.CompletionSuggestion suggestion = suggest.getSuggestion("product-suggest");

for (org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.completion.CompletionSuggestion.Entry entry : suggestion.getEntries()) {
     for (org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.completion.CompletionSuggestion.Entry.Option option : entry) {
        SearchHit hit = option.getHit();
        System.out.println(hit.getSourceAsString());
     }
}
```

**There are two problems:**

1. you are using wrong suggester name `search` but it is `product-suggest`.
2. You are not casting it. So you are getting only parent class options from suggester. Once you assign it to a proper type, you will get `hits` from that you cam get `_source`

---

## **Older answer:**

```
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils; //import
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

String responseEntity = EntityUtils.toString(searchResponse.getEntity());
JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(responseEntity).getAsJsonObject();
            JsonArray completionSUggesterArr = obj.getAsJsonObject("suggest").getAsJsonArray("completion-suggester");
            System.out.println(completionSUggesterArr.get(0).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("options"));

for(int i = 0; i < completionSUggesterArr.size(); i++) {
        JsonArray arr = completionSUggesterArr.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("options").getAsJsonArray();
        System.out.println(arr.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_source"));
}
```

This one is for low level client.

Comment: `SearchResponse` object doesn't have `getEntity` method

Comment: There is not method `searchResponse.getEntity()`, which type is `searchResponse` in your sample?

Comment: @user13674325 You are still referring older answer. Please check the first code.